# Are there tools to auto-generate Android POJO classes with Room Annotations

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-annotations, android-database

I have been using SqliteOpenHelper in Android for a long time.

In complex projects when the schema is big and there are many relationships, I use an online [tool](https://erdplus.com/) to design the ERD, then it exports for me the SQL code that builds the DB tables with all the relationships,field properties and constraints.

I can then directly paste it into my code and I am done!

Now, I want to take advantage of the ROOM library. However, I cannot find a tool that in this case would convert a schema to Java classes with the proper ROOM annotations, because manually creating the annotations for all relationships for a big project would be tedious and error prone.

Did anyone manage to find such a tool? Did one exist yet?

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: @kylexy1357 not yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no tool yet to auto-generate the POJO classes with ROOM annotations.One have to manually add the annotations.